# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)={1 \over 2} -{x^n \over {(x-1)^n+(x+1)^n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given this succession of function in $(0,+\infty)$ I have proved there is pointwise convergence in this interval to the function $f(x)={1 \over 2}$.
I have problem to study uniform convergence in particolar 
to calculate the superior extreme of $ |f_n(x)-f(x)| $ in $(0,+\infty)$

$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|g_n(x)|$ with $g_n(x)={{x^n}\over {(x-1)^n+(x+1)^n}}$
If I calculate $g'_n(x)$ is >0 in $(0,+\infty)$ so the Sup is $+\infty $ and there is 't uniform convergence?
Can I have convergence in $(0,a]$ with a>0?

Comment: Well, you've already got the answer: $$\lim g_n(x) = 0\implies \lim\sup g_n(x)=0$$ which shows the  uniform convergence...

Answer (score 1):

You've already proven your function $g_n$ is strictly monotonically increasing in $(0,+\infty)$, if you compute the limit for $x \to +\infty$, you'll see it tends to $1/2$. Also $g_n(0) = 0$. So you've done, $\forall x \in (0,+\infty), n$ natural $|g_n(x)| < M_n = \frac{1}{2}$